# Do event listeners persist in memory in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following article by Samer Buna...

https://medium.freecodecamp.org/node-js-child-processes-everything-you-need-to-know-e69498fe970a)

he talks about using `child_process.fork` in Node.js. In his example (near the bottom), he has a simple HTTP server that listens for request events and when an event occurs, he uses `child_process.fork` to create processes that does the long computation and then sends a message back to the parent upon completion. In order to return the result of the child process, he registers an event listener that listens for a message from the child and then returns the response. Pretty straight forward.

Once the parent process has received a message from the child and sends the response, what happens to the `compute.on` event listener? Does it persist in memory (event loop)? If the example handled 100 requests, would there not be 100 event listeners listening even though the requests had been returned?

**compute.js**

```
const longComputation = () => {
  let sum = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < 1e9; i++) {
    sum += i;
  };
  return sum;
};

process.on('message', (msg) => {
  const sum = longComputation();
  process.send(sum);
});
```

**server.js**

```
const http = require('http');
const { fork } = require('child_process');

const server = http.createServer();

server.on('request', (req, res) => {
  if (req.url === '/compute') {
    const compute = fork('compute.js');
    compute.send('start');
    compute.on('message', sum => {
      res.end(`Sum is ${sum}`);
    });
  } else {
    res.end('Ok')
  }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

Comment: I think a bigger issue here is that nothing is being done to dispose of the child processes being created. I suspect that if the event handler in server.js called `compute.disconnect()`, the child process would dispose itself and the event handler would naturally get cleaned up as well.

Answer (score 0):

Event listeners persist in memory until the EventEmitter they are attached to is destroyed.

In the case of your code, the child process and its event listener are never disposed of.  When a request is received, a brand-new child process is created, every time.  After the request callback completes, the reference to the forked process is garbage-collected, but the child process itself is still running in the background, creating lots of zombie processes and a memory leak.  Although, your event listeners will persist.

A better architecture may be to start a pool of child processes on application start (or, just a single process if your load is light), and then use those child processes as-needed to handle requests.

Comment: The example in the blog post was just for demonstration purposes for the `child_process.fork()` usage.